# How to build and run ios app in specified folder on device?

Tags: ios, xcode

After pressing build and run button in XCode I want to install my app to the specified folder on my device. For example, in directory "/DebugApps". Can I do it?

Comment: why do you want to achieve that? (I am just curious)

Comment: @jacky Boy We can create folder in real device and manage app. I guess while running app, he directly want the app to lie in particular folder in device.

Comment: @jacky Boy, I have a lot of apps on my iPhone and don't want to mix them with my projects, so I would like to put all of them in specified folder automatically.

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: This is really not a question because the simpliest way to do it is just to move built app by touch to specified folder on device and then app will be built in this folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would even want to do that, but no, that is an automated process and the corresponding folders are created by the system.